# Вводное слово "случайно"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

### "А ты не в этот лагерь ездила случайно?" – спросила она.

Как увидеть ту тонкую грань между вводным словом и обстоятельством  в предложении со "случайно"?

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном вами примере "случайно" вводное слово. Означает между прочим, кстати, случаем. 
Наречие имеет значение ненамеренно, непредвиденно.

Поэтому надо исходить из смысла. Нельзя сказать: ездить случайно. Поскольку глагол "ездить" предполагает повторяющиеся действие.

Comment: А почему Вы предполагаете, что в предложении допущена пунктуационная ошибка, а не стилистическая? :)

Comment: grizzly, а потому, что есть отрицательная частица "не''. СЛУЧАЕМ / СЛУЧАЙНО, вводное слово (в вопросительном предложении, с частицей «не») Справочник по пунктуации. Грамота.ру

Comment: Слова-то рядом (ездить случайно), но связи меж ними нет. Вопрос в другом: «Случайно(,) не в этот-ли лагерь?».

Comment: Вопросительные предложения с отрицанием бывают разные. "Не пропустил ли он эту запятую случайно?".  Впрочем, поддержу ответ и не буду дальше "троллить"; я хотел только сказать, что нужно было обратить внимание в ответе на пунктуационную ошибку.

Comment: А ты не в этот лагерь ездила, случайно?" Если вы про позиции, то, думаю, от позиции смысл не меняется.

Comment: Вы правы - разные. С этим никто не спорит. Но обратите внимание: наречие "случайно" в этом значении употребляется с глаголами совершенного вида.

Comment: А насчет ошибки, я не уверен. Может, автор сомневался насчет запятой, поэтому и не поставил.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **А ты не в этот лагерь ездила, случайно?" – спросила она.**

СЛУЧАЕМ / СЛУЧАЙНО, вводное слово (в вопросительном предложении, с частицей «не»). Вы, случайно, не из Москвы?
http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_680

Можно заехать/приехать куда-то случайно, но ездить случайно нельзя. Поэтому вариант с обстоятельством исключается.

― Я заехал случайно к Сергею Степановичу... [П. Д. Боборыкин. Китай-город (1882)]

Соответственно, чтобы различать обстоятельство и вводное слово, нужно сначала убедиться, что оба значения возможны.

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто, хотя зависит от ситуации. Рассмотрим наиболее типичные случаи.

Если Вы автор мысли, то Вы знаете, выражаете ли Вы сомнение в предложении с отрицанием, или предполагаете/сообщаете о каком-то случайном событии.

Если Вы читаете чужой текст, тогда ещё проще — по знакам препинания.

Если в устной речи, тогда из контекста и интонации (в этом случае проще всего ошибиться).

Comment: Но что делать, если попалось, например, отдельное предложение, как в вопросе, и оно ни с чем не связано?

Comment: Так ведь я говорю, что это самый простой случай. Раз запятой нет, значит, обстоятельство. Пример: "она" взяла билет в случайное место (например, монетку подкинула), а подруга спрашивает, не в этот ли лагерь она совершила эту случайную поездку.

Comment: Получается, в значении случайности не обособляется, а в значении, не знаю, некого любопытства ставится запятая?

Comment: Да, именно так.